# Meaning of an algebra having "sufficiently many primitive idempotents"?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

This is a phrase Ringel uses a few times in his writing, and I'm not sure exactly what he means by it. The context is that we have a quiver $Q$ with path algebra $\mathbf{k}Q$. If $Q$ is not a finite quiver, then $\mathbf{k}Q$ will not have a unit, but it does have *sufficiently many primitive idempotents*. I'm not sure what constitutes "sufficiently many". In other writings he refers to a general $\mathbf{k}$-algebra having *sufficiently many primitive idempotents,* so maybe this just means the algebra is sufficiently like the path algebra of a quiver? I'm only familiar with this sort of a phrasing of a category having *sufficiently many projectives/injectives*.

The exact paper I'm looking at is Butler and Ringel's [Auslander-Reiten Sequences with Few Middle Terms and Applications to String Algebras](https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/record/1776051) on page 157.

Comment: I don't know about the "primitive" part, but sometimes (in representation theory of p-adic groups, for example), sufficiently many idempotents means that for every finite collection of idempotents $e_1 , \ldots , e_n$ there exists an idempotent $e$ such that $e e_i = e_i e = e_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ (a typical thing to imagine is functions with compact support on a space w.r.t. pointwise multiplication - then characteristic functions of compacts are idempotents, and you can take unions of finite collections of compacts...)

Comment: It should mean that the ring has a finite complete set of primitive idempotents.

Comment: To fill out @Sasha's remark, probably it should also be required that, for every element $r$ of the ring, there is an idempotent $e$ such that $er=re=r$. (I do not offhand know what "primitive" should mean here.)

Comment: For non unital rings this means $R\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}Re_i$ with the $e_i$ orthogonal primitive idempotents. The index set can be infinite. This is clearly the case for the path algebra of a quiver.

Comment: The condition @PaulGattett mentions is usually called having local units

Comment: If the quiver is finite then the index set is finite? Then it is the same as finite complete set of primitive idempotents.

Comment: @paulgarrett Oh, of course. Thank you.

Comment: @paulgarrett In the context of path algebras, their is an idempotent element $e_i$ for each vertex $i$ of the quiver, and these idempotents are orthogonal. Since they're orthogonal any sum of them will be idempotent too, so *primitive* refers to these $e_i$, the idempotents that can't be written as a sum of two other non-trivial idempotents.

Comment: @MarkSapir Yeah if the quiver is finite, then everything is fine. It's the case where "*if $Q$ is not a finite quiver ... $\mathbf{k}Q$ will have sufficiently many primitive idempotents.*" In this case there are infinitely many pairwise orthogonal primitive idempotents. One for each vertex. Is infinitely many sufficiently many? ;) Sasha's response makes sense in this case though, so I believe her right now.

Comment: Yes, "sufficiently many" means the direct sum decomposition as in Steinberg's comment. That is true in the infinite case too (obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the info, @MikePierce!

Comment: Let me add that having the direct sum decomposition as a left module is equivalent to having it as a right module. And it implies Sasha and Paul's conditions which are much weaker.

Comment: I looked back at the references on rings with enough idempotents and I had misremembered things.  One should assume that the ring decomposes as a direct sum of the e_iR as a right module too.  You don't get it for free.  I got confused because a line in a paper about Leavitt path algebras seemed to imply that.